# Get the value of hidden column in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am using a Gridview and wondering if there is way to hide a column from the Gridview but still be able to access the hidden column value.

I set visible= false for the column that I want to hide but when I try to get the value of the column, the value in the column is empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way I have gotten values from Invisible GridView Columns is using the DataKeyNames attribute.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView" DataKeyNames="ColName1, ColName2">
</asp:GridView>
```

then to access the data

```
var data = GridView.DataKeys[RowIndex].Values[KeyIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the RowDataBound event, get the row DataItem:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var dataRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

    var data = dataRowView["FieldName"].ToString();
}
```