# c# Delete records from database using grid view with a link button

Tags: c#, database, gridview

I have a grid view that looks like this for example :

[image]

I need to delete the selected row where there is a hidden column activityID and taskID which I set visible to false because I need their value to delete it from the database.

So here is my code:

```
 protected void gvQuestion_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            Model.question del = new Model.question(); // Entitiy CRUD
            del.ActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[2].ToString()); // Value of ActivityID column in GV
            del.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[3].ToString()); // Value of TaskID column in GV
            daoQuestion.Delete(del);

        }

        daoQuestion.Save(); 
    }

    protected void gvQuestion_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

I followed the guide here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111037/Delete-Data-in-GridView-Using-Template-Button

But I am using the entity framework to delete, however I get the error of `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`, and the error lies in the delete statement. I searched for the error, and it says it might be a null value. How do I solve this problem?

Btw , i populated this grid view from Database as well.

Comment: what is `daoQuestion`?

Comment: thats a CRUD class file

Comment: I have a question on your Cells[index]. Is Cells[2] really for ActivityID? Because what I see it belongs to "Delete" column.

Comment: do u mean Cells[0] is the first column?

Comment: i have activityid and taskid column like this : QuestionNo , ActivityID , TaskID , QuestionCntent , delete ... i set activity and task column visible false .

Comment: Then if that's the case ActivityID should be Cells[1] and TaskID Cells[2]. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yup tried it , still the same error

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the ActivityID and/or the TaskID has the correct Numeric Values?

Comment: previously i was using boundfield and i searched that when u hide columns in boundfield , u cant access the value so i convert it to templatefield..

Answer (score 2):

```
var itemToDel = context.Questions.FirstOrDefault(q=>q.ActivityID = aid && q.TaskID == tid);

if(itemToDel !=null){
    context.Questions.DeleteObject(itemToDel);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

To Get values from current deleting row, try below

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

GridViewRow row = gvQuestion.Rows[index];

var aid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text); 
var tid  = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text);
```

Comment: i have to delete by getting the  selected row columns value of the grid view . i tried to change aid and tid to gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[2].ToString() , doesn't work .

Comment: @user2376998 have you debug and check the values for tid and aid?

Comment: yes it gives me null , i think the problems lies in how i get value from the selected rows' columns ...

Comment: hmm value still returns null , i tried to add template field and add a label control , then save the value to label control , still doesn't work which means the value is already 0 to begin with is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to query the model first like the one below. Im not too familliar with linq, just correct the syntax if wrong.

```
Model.question del = new Model.question();

var item = from d in del
           where d.ActivityID == Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[2].ToString());
           and d.TaskID == Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[3].ToString());
           select d;

daoQuestion.Delete(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your conversion is the culprit, that is, the values of your cells are converted to `Int32` and if it empty by the way it will give the error `"Input String was not in correct format"`. So, this one below is potential for error:

```
del.ActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text); 
del.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text);
```

So, why not use TryParse instead and check if there is value first like:

```
 if (e.CommandName == "delete")
     {
        int ActID, TskID;
        Int32.TryParse(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text, out ActID);
        Int32.TryParse(gvQuestion.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text, out TskID);
        // Try to Debug here to show the value of ActID and TskID if you have the right values.
        if (ActID>0 && TskID > 0)
        {
        Model.question del = new Model.question(); // Entitiy CRUD
        del.ActivityID = ActID; // Value of ActivityID column in GV
        del.TaskID = TskID; // Value of TaskID column in GV
        daoQuestion.Delete(del);

        }

    }
```

Try also `DataKeys` instead of `Rows[].Cells[]` like:

```
 gvQuestion.DataKeys(e.EditIndex).Item("ActivityID");
 gvQuestion.DataKeys(e.EditIndex).Item("TaskID");
```

Or:

```
 gvQuestion.DataKeys[0].Values[2];
 gvQuestion.DataKeys[0].Values[3];
```

See sample links [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1106692.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127662/get-the-value-of-hidden-column-in-gridview) for reference

Comment: How about the Index, that is, from 2 to 1 and from 3 to 2 basing on the order of the columns that you provided under the comment of your OP.

Comment: Sorry , what index , i dun get what u mean? sorry new to this

Comment: I mean the index for your Cells[indexhere] property. But you already answered this question of mine on your original post so don't bother anymore. However, did you try to debug just to check the value for AcitivityID and TaskID if it has values on the first place?

Comment: yeah but it seems that i can't access the values of the hidden columns

Comment: i tried using datakeys but it gave an error of  The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

Comment: Check my new answer above.

Comment: tried it , both values 0, so i guess i can't access the hidden columns values? but i even tried with datakeys and convert it to templatefield ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the `DataKeyNames="Id"` in the Gridview is set to Question ID and for deleting use the following code,

```
        protected void grid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
              if (e.CommandName.ToUpper().ToString() == "DELETE")
              {
                 ViewState["id"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim();
                 Model.question del = new Model.question();
                del.ActivityID = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuesViewState["id"]).ToString());             
                del.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["id"]).ToString());             
                daoQuestion.Delete(del);
              }
             daoQuestion.Save(); 
        }
```