# How do I get the value from a hidden column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here's the code I have, which works perfectly with visible columns. However, I need to be able to get the value of certain columns that are invisible:

```
protected void btnSearchForSchedules_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            var schedulesTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvShows.Rows)
            {
                if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox) gvr.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
                    {
                        string baseURL = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SchedulesAPI"];

                        string dataSource = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
                        string showId = gvr.Cells[2].Text; //this column is hidden so I'm getting a NULL here
                        string episodeId = gvr.Cells[4].Text;

                        string callingURL = baseURL + "?datasource=" + dataSource + "&showid=" + showId;

                        if (episodeId != "&nbsp;")
                        {
                            callingURL = callingURL + "&episodeId=" + episodeId;
                        }

                        schedulesTable = Transporter.GetDataTableFromAPI(callingURL);

                        ds.Tables.Add(schedulesTable);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone explain to me how I'd do this:

string showId = gvr.Cells[2].Text;

if the column is not visible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4127662/2387010

Comment: I saw the other question but I don't understand how to make it work in my code.

Comment: This http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/e7bf9a9c-f5c6-4b03-8481-652dc1c9d7b0/ would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get a hidden column value, you specify `DataKeyNames` property for that GridView in aspx page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="column1" ...>
```

Then you can retrieve that column value as below in code behind.

```
string showId = (string) GridView1.DataKeys[2].Value.ToString();
```