# How do I reference hidden gridView cells on my web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is a .aspx page.

I currently have this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvShows.Rows)
            {
                if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox) gvr.FindControl("cbSelect")).Checked)
                    {
                        string dataSource = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Which works if the column is visible.

However, the gridView column is now hidden but I still need to capture its value.

How would I go about converting the above code to get the dataSource value which is in a hidden column?

Comment: is this a WebForm .aspx or MVC or what?

Comment: this is web form .aspx

Comment: maybe my answer for other question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715983/how-to-get-the-cell-value-by-column-name-not-by-index-in-gridview-in-asp-net/9716160#9716160

Comment: Take also a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127662/get-the-value-of-hidden-column-in-gridview